# System updates not showing up in app store after system re-install, how do I fix this?

Tags: high-sierra, mac-appstore, software-update

So I recently did some spring cleaning on my Mac and re-installed the system.

I installed High Sierra 10.13.1, but I'm experiencing some issues with bringing it up to 10.13.4: namely, the updates aren't showing up in the app store.

I'm a developer, and in trying to update Xcode, I keep getting an error saying "your system isn't up to date, do you want to install an older version of Xcode instead?".

So why isn't my app store keeping me up to date on this? Is there anything I can do to get the system up to speed?